# Making VB Browser Make Facebook Status

Tags: facebook, vba

I am trying to make a vb script to log into my facebook and update my status. The problem is, the submit button does not have an ID I can find using the page info with Chrome. The script I have so far is:

```
    Try
        Dim fileReader As String
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("pathtotext") ' I sensoored my path
        fileReader2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("pathtotext") 'I sensored my path
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", fileReader2)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", fileReader)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginbutton").InvokeMember("click")
    Catch ex As Exception
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_10").SetAttribute("value", "Can I make a   status?")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
    End Try
```

All of this works, except the submit button. I used "submit" because that was the type and no ID is showing up. Thanks in advance for all help.

P.S - For future reference, how did you find the id for this button? "If you give a starving man a fish he shall be filled; teach him to fish, however and he shall never go hungry again" - Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Dim htmlElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        For Each ClickOnElementButton As HtmlElement In htmlElements
            If ClickOnElementButton.InnerText = "Post" Then
                ClickOnElementButton.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

instead of the old code

Comment: You can format the code by selecting the text, and clicking the `{ }` button in the text editor.  It will make the code easier to read....